# DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: javascript

```js
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageSelectMenu } = require('discord.js');
module.exports.run = async (bot,message,args) => {
  try{
    let date = new Date();
    const currentDate = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
    const currentDate1 = date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    let user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    let support = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "× Саппорт");
    if(!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === support.id)) {
        const Segnauro_1 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#303136')
        .setAuthor({ name: `${message.author.tag}` })
        .setTitle(`Взаимодействие с Пользователем`)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
        .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, У **Вас недостаточно прав**!`)
        .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${message.author.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });
        return message.channel.send({ embeds: [Segnauro_1] });
    } else {
        if(!args[0]) {
            const Segnauro_1 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setAuthor({ name: `${message.author.tag}` })
            .setTitle(`Взаимодействие с Пользователем`)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, Вы **не указали** Пользователя!`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${message.author.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });
            return message.channel.send({ embeds: [Segnauro_1] });
        };
        if(!user) {
            const Segnauro_1 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setAuthor({ name: `${message.author.tag}` })
            .setTitle(`Взаимодействие с Пользователем`)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, Пользователь **не найден**!`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${message.author.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });
            return message.channel.send({ embeds: [Segnauro_1] });
        };
        if(!user.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "1028138123047219290")) {
            const Segnauro_1 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setAuthor({ name: `${message.author.tag}` })
            .setTitle(`Взаимодействие с Пользователем`)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, Пользователь **уже пропущен**!`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${message.author.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });
            return message.channel.send({ embeds: [Segnauro_1] });
        } else {
            const Segnauro_1 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setAuthor({ name: `${message.author.tag}` })
            .setTitle(`Взаимодействие с Пользователем`)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, Выберите **действие** над ${user}!`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${message.author.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });
            const Segnauro_2 = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('primary')
                    .setLabel(`Смена Гендерной роли`)
                    .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                    .setDisabled('false'),
            );
        
            const Segnauro_3 = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('primary1')
                    .setLabel(`Выдать Не допуск`)
                    .setStyle('DANGER')
                    .setDisabled('false'),
            );
            message.reply({ embeds: [Segnauro_1], components: [Segnauro_2, Segnauro_3] })
        };
        bot.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
            const Segnauro_1 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setAuthor({ name: `${interaction.user.tag}` })
            .setTitle(`Взаимодействие с Пользователем`)
            .setThumbnail(interaction.user.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, Выберите **Гендер** для ${user}!`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${interaction.user.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });
            const Segnauro_10 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setAuthor({ name: `${interaction.user.tag}` })
            .setTitle(`Взаимодействие с Пользователем`)
            .setThumbnail(interaction.user.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, Вы установили **Мужской** Гендер для ${user}!`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${interaction.user.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });
            const Segnauro_11 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setAuthor({ name: `${interaction.user.tag}` })
            .setTitle(`Взаимодействие с Пользователем`)
            .setThumbnail(interaction.user.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, Вы установили **Женский** Гендер для ${user}!`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${interaction.user.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });
            const Segnauro_123 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setAuthor({ name: `${interaction.user.tag}` })
            .setTitle(`Взаимодействие с Пользователем`)
            .setThumbnail(interaction.user.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, Вы выдали **Не допуск** для ${user}!`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${interaction.user.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });

            const Segnauro_1234 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setTitle('Выдача не допуска')
            .setDescription(`${user} получил **не допуск** на сервере **Segnauro**`)
            .addField('Не допуск был выдан', `__!__<@${interaction.user.id}>`)
            .addField('Причина не допуска', `__!__Нарушение правил`)
            .setThumbnail(interaction.user.avatarURL())
            .setFooter({ text: `Использовал ⌭ ${interaction.user.tag} | ${currentDate1}, в ${currentDate}` });

            const Segnauro_2 = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
            new MessageSelectMenu()
            .setCustomId('select')
            .setPlaceholder('Выбор Гендерной роли')
            .addOptions([
              {
                label: 'Мужской',
                description: 'Смена Гендерной роли на Мужскую',
                value: 'one',
              },
              {
                label: 'Женский',
                description: 'Смена Гендерной роли на Женскую',
                value: 'two',
              },
            ]),
            )
            if(interaction.customId == "primary") {
                await interaction.reply({ embeds: [Segnauro_1], components: [Segnauro_2] })
            };
            if(interaction.customId == "select") {
                if(interaction.values[0] == "one") {
                    let gender_1 = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "1028137992969273406");
                    let gender_2 = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "1028138123047219290");
                    user.roles.add(gender_1)
                    user.roles.remove(gender_2)
                    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [Segnauro_10] })
                };
                if(interaction.values[0] == "two") {
                    let gender_1 = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "1028138049814675568");
                    let gender_2 = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "1028138123047219290");
                    user.roles.add(gender_1)
                    user.roles.remove(gender_2)
                    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [Segnauro_11] })
                };
            };
            if(interaction.customId == "primary1") {
                await interaction.update({ embeds: [Segnauro_123] })
                let nd_1 = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "1028138732295045180");
                user.roles.add(nd_1)
                await bot.channels.cache.find('1028138865590018078').send({ embeds: [Segnauro_1234] })
            };
        });
    };
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(`1. ${err.name} - Наименование ошибки\n2. ${err.message} - Описание ошибки\n3. ${err.stack} - Подробности ошибки`)
  };
};
module.exports.help = {
    name: "verify"
};
```

Comment: Поставьте где ни будь знак вопроса что ли... А лучше детализируйте, где вы получаете данную ошибку и в какой момент.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.